# Renaming an image after storing in the database

Tags: c#, file-io

How do you rename an image after storing in a database? I already tried using `System.IO.File.Move(oldpath, newpath)` but I'm getting an error

`'System.IO.IOException'
Additional information: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Is there any other way to do this?

Here's my code

```
byte[] imageID = null;               
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.pathID.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageID = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length); 
string login = "server=localhost;database=id;uid=root;password=root;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(login);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO picture(`Picture_Employee`) VALUES (@EMP);";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP", imageID);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Picture Added");

//sampleID.Text contains ID# of Employee and label1.Text contains the name of the employee
string newpath = sampleID.Text + "-" + label1.Text;
System.IO.File.Move(pathID.Text, newpath);
```

After storing the image to the database I want it to rename it as ID#-EmployeeName

Comment: Show us the code you use to store it in the database. You've likely left a file handle open.. causing your issue.

Comment: Have you closed the file before trying to move it? You have to.

Comment: is closing the file similar to closing the connection to the database?

Comment: `fstream.Close` will close the file and release the file back to the operating system so that you can then move it. Think about having a pdf file open in Adobe reader and trying to rename it before you close the file, you can't because the program has the file in use and locked. Same principle here except your code opens the file to read the contents and it still hasn't open because you never closed it. It's similar to closing your database connection  in that it's closing SOMETHING but it's still different.

Comment: Also make sure you are closing anything holding some sort of handle and disposing anything that's using unmanaged resources (items implementing IDisposable) : file streams, database connections, the binary reader. The command object can't be closed but should need to be disposed. Look up a `using` block which will handle all of this for you, even when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: One other note, MySQL is neither here nor there in regards to your problem, you just happen to be using it in between the two different file operations (read, move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you should close the `FileStream` similar to how you're closing the database.

Event better, since these both implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface you can use C#'s [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to call `Dispose` (which internally calls `Close()` automatically):

```
byte[] imageID = null;               
using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.pathID.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    imageID = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length); 
    string login = "server=localhost;database=id;uid=root;password=root;";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(login))
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO picture(`Picture_Employee`) VALUES (@EMP);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP", imageID);  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Picture Added");
    }

//sampleID.Text contains ID# of Employee and label1.Text contains the name of the employee
string newpath = sampleID.Text + "-" + label1.Text;
System.IO.File.Move(pathID.Text, newpath);
```

Notice that I removed `conn.Close()` as the `using` statement will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file stream. Because you never close it, it is still in use and the operating system is unable to move the file. You can do this by calling `Close()` on the stream object:

`fstream.Close()`

See the comments I posted on your question regarding best practices to ensure that you won't run into issues like this when performing similar tasks.